# How to insert javascript var into path on Twig?

Tags: javascript, php, symfony, twig

I want to insert a var declared in javascript into my path to redirect my page.

My code is:

```
 var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
 windows.location = {{ path("mylink", {id: id}) }};
```

But I can't know how can insert my var id into path, because when I try this I get error, I'm trying to parse this with +' myvar '+ so concatenating text but I can't.

How can I concatenate or add my var into path?

Thanks!

Comment: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/171203/what-are-the-differences-between-server-side-and-client-side-programming

Comment: It doesn't work that way. Everything that your server side (PHP/Twig) does is done *way* before any JS runs. By the time your JS is running, PHP has absolutely no control over what's happening.

Answer (score 1):

Because PHP is executed on server side, you need to bypass by this way:

```
 var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
 var path = {{ path("mylink", {id: 0420}) }};

 windows.location = path.replace("0420", id);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this without having to use javascript `replace` function. However, it requires some work.

1. Create `Twig` extension to decode URL:

   ```
   namespace AppBundle\Twig\Extension;

   class UrlDecodeExtension extends \Twig_Extension
   {
       public function getFilters()
       {
           return array(
               new \Twig_SimpleFilter('url_decode', array($this, 'UrlDecodeFilter'))
           );
       }

       public function UrlDecodeFilter($url)
       {
           return urldecode($url);
       }

       public function getName()
       {
           return 'url_decode_extension';
       }
   }
   ```
2. Register your new extension:

   ```
   url_decode_extension:
       class: AppBundle\Twig\Extension\UrlDecodeExtension
       tags:
           - { name: twig.extension }
   ```
3. Finally, use it in your `Twig` template:

   ```
   var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
   windows.location = {{ path("mylink", {id: "%s"}) | url_decode | format('"+id+"') | raw }};
   ```

This is how it is going to render in the browser:

```
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
window.location("/your/rendered/url/"+id+"");
```

Answer (score 0):

You should really consider using [FOSJsRoutingBundle](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/index.html). It is one of the most commonly used bundles. Its only purpose is to expose the routes you want to client side. Once installed, your code would be :

```
var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
windows.location = Routing.generate("mylink", {id: id});
```